# How to copy <table class="table"> from another page to my page by entering the link

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to see on my website the edited `<table class = "plan">` from the school website through my css and js code.

I tried `<iframe>` but that's not what I'm looking for and `$ ('# target-div').` `Load ('example.com');` but it is:

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://zstil.type.pl/plan/index.html' from origin 'http: // localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'header is present on the requested resource.'

Any ideas?

Comment: CORS is default disabled across origins, IE, Server A cannot request a JS script on Server B for security reasons. Server B needs to allow Server A to send such requests. If you're trying to requests external servers, this won't work unless they enable CORS for your domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a service like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ and make an ajax call using jquery: -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myUrl = 'http://zstil.type.pl/plan/plany/o1.html';
    var proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
    var finalURL = proxy + myUrl;
    // With the get method
    $.get(finalURL, function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

You could then use regex to parse the data table you want from the HTML and inject that into your own page using jquery append function